# Simple regex not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

My regex is next

```
/^(\.\w*)|(\d*\.?\d*)$/
```

it should works well for float numbers (`123.23`, `12.`, `.56`) and any words that starts from dot.
I was confused when
`/^(\.\w*)|(\d*\.?\d*)$/.test("qweasdzxc"); // return true`
but without OR:

```
/^(\.\w*)$/.test("qweasdzxc"); // return false   
/^(\d*\.?\d*)$/.test("qweasdzxc"); // return false
```

On [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%5C.%5Cw%2a%29%7C%28%5Cd%2a%5C.?%5Cd%2a%29%24&input=All%20these%20match%3a%0A%0A12%0A12.2%0A1236.32%0A123.123%0A0%0A%0AThese%20don%27t%3a%0A%0Asdhdfsh%0A) all works well

Comment: The equivalent expressions without OR are `^(\.\w*)` and `(\d*\.?\d*)$` and the latter is `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
/^((\.\w*)|(\d*\.?\d*))$/.test("qweasdzxc"); // false
/^((\.\w*)|(\d*\.?\d*))$/.test(".5"); // true
```

You must encapsulate regex condition (A|B).

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
/^((\.\w*)|(\d*\.?\d*))$/
```

You need to wrap both the OR conditions within another `(..)`.

Other wise it is interpreted as `^(\.\w*)` or `(\d*\.?\d*)$` instead of `^` and ( `(\.\w*)` or `(\d*\.?\d*)` ) and `$`.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rz3uf/1/)